# NEGAR CARACTERES ESPECIALES EN UN INPUT

Tags: javascript, html

**NEGAR CARACTERES ESPECIALES**

Tengo la siguiente función en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```js
function escapar_caracteres(obj) {
  obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9-\s+@+.+-]/,'');
}
```

1. Lo que realiza esa función es dejar los caracteres de A a la Z.
2. Pero lo que quiero que realice es que si no está dentro de `/[A-Za-z0-9-\s+@+.+-]/` me lo remplace con `''`.

Bueno, alguna solución estaba pensando en:

```js
function escapar_caracteres(obj) {
  obj.value = obj.value.replace(!/[A-Za-z0-9-\s+@+.+-]/,'');
}
```

**Mi `input` esta así:**

```html
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control"
 placeholder="Nombres..."
 onkeyup="escapar_caracteres(this)"
 onchange="escapar_caracteres(this)"
>
```

Algo por estilo. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Bueno si funciona pero tiene algunas vulnerabilidades  puedes copiar los caracteres especial y sigue funcionando mientras con esta función de javascript evita el copia y ingresos de caracteres especiales .

Comment: Con esta función de javascript, lo único que lograrás es frustrar al usuario. Si cada vez que me equivoco tipeando un carácter no permitido, se reemplaza **todo** el `value` por un caracter nulo, deberé empezar a escribir nuevamente todo desde el principio. Por otro lado, las validaciones deberían ser posteriores y no inmediatas. Tal como está tu código, es posible copiar texto y pegarlo en tu `input` y todo se viene al trasto. Mi sugerencia es que no frustres al usuario y valides la data al momento de hacer el `submit` o mediante una alerta visual y no reemplazando caracteres. Saludos

Comment: Bueno si tienes razón gracias lo tomare en cuenta